# Fetch redux state after API Call is successfully completed

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created one dialog box for updating the user details.
I have three redux states updateUserLoading, updateUserError, updateUserSuccess

I am not able to figure out how shall I call/show update successful message to user, below code is accessing old value of updateUserSuccess

```
  const { updateRoleSuccess, updateRoleError, updateRoleLoading }: UpdateRoleState = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.updateRole);
  
  onSubmit: async (data) => {
            await updateRole(data.editRoleId,data.priviledges);
            await fetchRoles()    

            updateRoleSuccess == true && setNotification("Role updated Successfully")

    }
```

I tried putting it inside useeffect too but the problem is I am using above

```
   useEffect(() => {
        updateRoleSuccess == true && setNotification("Role updated Successfully")
    }, [updateRoleSuccess])
```

But the problem is it works fine for the first time only, second time when I open dialog box it shows me "Role updated Successfully" notification because updateRoleSuccess was set to true when I made changes first time and closed box

Answer (score 0):

You can include `updateRoleSuccess` in `useEffect` and update your notification like below.

```
useEffect(() => {
     if (updateRoleSuccess) setNotification("Role updated Successfully");
}, [updateRoleSuccess]);
```

I am guessing you are getting the status on `updateRoleSuccess` (true or false) based on api call.

Comment: I tried that but I am using the above component as a dialog box, and whenever I close that dialog box and reopen it shows notification again because previously updateRoleSuccess was set to true

Comment: Update the `updateRoleSuccess` to false in the redux state since you are making an API call and need to know whether the API is succeeded or not.